# BIP Difference between final and active

Tags: lightning-network, bip, micropaymentchannels

What is the difference in the Bitcoins Improvements Proposals between the final status and the active status?

According to the wiki

> An Proposed BIP may progress to Final only when specific criteria reflecting real-world adoption has occurred. This is different for each BIP depending on the nature of its proposed changes, which will be expanded on below. Evaluation of this status change should be objectively verifiable, and/or be discussed on the development mailing list.
>
> A process BIP may change status from Draft to Active when it achieves rough consensus on the mailing list. Such a proposal is said to have rough consensus if it has been open to discussion on the development mailing list for at least one month, and no person maintains any unaddressed substantiated objections to it. Addressed or obstructive objections may be ignored/overruled by general agreement that they have been sufficiently addressed, but clear reasoning must be given in such circumstances.

However they seem to be interchangeable to some sense. I am particularly interested for the BIP 0112 (OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY), because of the application of the Lightning Network. Its status is final. Should I assume this OPCODE is already usable and will be/is the one used for the implementation of the Lightning Network?

Comment: Can you please link to the Wiki where you got that, I read it on BIP 002 and don't remember it saying exactly what your Wiki quote does.

Comment: it is [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0002.mediawiki)

Answer (score 2):

"Active" is used for Process BIPs, it is not used for Standards Track or Informational BIPs, which use "Final".

A quote from BIP 2: "A process BIP may change status from Draft to Active when it achieves rough consensus on the mailing list."